# WRF JASPERLIB or JASPERINC not found

Tags: bash

I am getting this message when I am trying to compile something called WRF:

```
$JASPERLIB or $JASPERINC not found in environment. Using default values for library paths...
```

I have tried to do both set and export

```
JASPERLIB=/home/jp2nyy/WRF/LIBRARIES/grib2/lib
JASPERINC=/home/jp2nyy/WRF/LIBRARIES/grib2/include
```

I am trying to follow the steps on this page: http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php where it suggests `setenv` but I believe `setenv` is not Bash.

Comment: You probably need to change "xxxx" to your actual user name and you probably do not need the . at the end of "JASPERINC=/home/xxxx/WRF/LIBRARIES/grib2/include. " If you posted "xxxx" to obscure something , well it makes it difficult to impossible to help you if we do not know what you are doing and how.

Comment: According to the documentation that is a common message and you should next be given choices of what to use. See http://www.dtcenter.org/wrf-nmm/users/OnLineTutorial/NMM/Compilation/wps_compile2.php

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I am trying to run the WRF-ARW not NMM but I got told that Jasperlib is necessary for the executables in WPS.

Comment: If what you have posted are the commands you ran, then file with WRF as this is not in the ubuntu repos and as far as I can tell your commands are valid.